# JTable clickable column header

Tags: java, swing, header, jtable

I am trying to make a clickable column header (so that a method would be called whenever one's clicked). 

 link to image (since I don't have 10 reputation yet) http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/5764/clickablecolumn.png

The column header is in red rectangle.

What I've done so far is responding whenever any column field (such as the one with James, Benny-G and Rokas) is pressed.
The code:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Mouse clicked");
        TableColumnModel cModel = table.getColumnModel();//cModel - column model
        int selColumn = cModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());//gets the selected column by clicked x coordinate
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to add a mouse listener to the table header, which is represented by `JTableHeader`:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(4, 3) {
  {
    getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        int index = convertColumnIndexToModel(columnAtPoint(mouseEvent.getPoint()));
        if (index >= 0) {
          System.out.println("Clicked on column " + index);
        }
      };
    });
  }
}));

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```